# Handling different input file types

Tags: c++, gps

I am creating a program to read RINEX files (GPS text files essentially) and pass the observations to a separate class to process them. There are several RINEX versions, right now there are 7 commonly used formats (v2, v2.10, v2.11, v3.0, v3.01, v3.01, v3.02, v3.03), each with a slight variation on how the data is presented in the file, so would require different ways to read the file in. What would be the most appropriate way to handle this, so if a new version comes out its easy to handle. Also how would I handle the input at runtime, one user

Right now I was thinking of having a base class RinexObs and creating a superclass for each version. Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

I have shortened the code below, but shows what I was going with. I know its an inefficient way, just cant wrap my head around other ways to do this.

```
class RinexObs {
    // All possible rinex versions
    enum class Versions {
       v2_0,
       v2_10,
       v2_11,
       // and others
     }
    // Override this method with every superclass 
    virtual double GetData() = 0;
    // Method to determine the Rinex version. I cant tell
    // the rinex version until after opening the file and reading the first
    // the first line, hence why this method is in the base class.
    Versions GetRinexVersion () { };
}; // end of class RinexObs

class RinexV2 : public RinexObs {
    // Override base class
     double GetData() {
     // Implement code how to read V2 files
  }
}; // end of class RinexV2

class RinexV210 : public RinexObs {
    // Override base class
    double GetData() {
        // Implement code how to read V2.10 files
   }
}; // end of class RinexV210

int main() {
    RinexObs input_file;
    // ... code to open file properly
    // Get the rinex version
    RinexObs::Versions rinex_version = input_file.GetRinexVersion();
    // Something to hold the data from the rinex file
    double data = 0;
    // Based off the rinex_version read the data
    switch(rinex_version) {
    case RinexObs::Versions::v2_0:
        input_file = new RinexV2();
        data = input_file.GetData();
        break;
    // all other cases
   } // end of switch
} // end of main
```

Comment: Perhaps use a factory or `switch` statement to call functions based on version?  Also factor out any common code between the reading so that the various readers can share code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews would you keep the implementation that I have, base class and inherit all versions from that?

Comment: Review the factory design pattern.  It should answer your question about base and child classes.

Comment: What does "Also how would I handle the input at runtime, one user" mean? Clarify what "input at runtime" is.